# syntax error with '$' sign ; Cheetah / bash

Tags: bash, cheetah

I work on a script running Cheetah ; at some point there are some bash commands and I got a syntax error ("Error in the Python code which Cheetah generated for this template").

The line involved is :

```
&& name=$(echo '\$another_variable'".phy" | cut -d _ -f 1)
```

The syntax error being on the very first '$' sign. It worked yesterday so I'm kind of confused ...

The whole code is wrraped in a xml tag :

```
<command><![CDATA[
    ln -s '$input' '$input.element_identifier' &&

    BlastAlign -i '$input.element_identifier'
    -m $advanced_option.m
    #if $advanced_option.r != ""
        -r $advanced_option.r
    #end if
    #if $advanced_option.x != ""
        -x $advanced_option.x
    #end if
    -n $advanced_option.n
    #if $advanced_option.s != 0
        -s $advanced_option.s
    #end if

    && mkdir outputs

    && name=$(echo '\$input.element_identifier'".phy" | cut -d _ -f 1)

    && number=$(grep '/' '\$input.element_identifier'".phy" | wc -l)

    && new_file=$name"_sp"$number".phy"
    && mv '\$input.element_identifier'".phy" '$new_file'
    && new_file2=$name"_sp"$number".nxs"
    && mv '\$input.element_identifier'".nxs" '$new_file2'
    && cp '$new_file' outputs/
    && cp '$new_file2' outputs/

    #if $fasta_out.value == True
        && python $__tool_directory__/scripts/S01_phylip2fasta.py /outputs/'$new_file' outputs/$name"_sp"$number".fasta"
    #end if

]]></command>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But it looks like you're trying to do this: `name=${another_variable%%_*}`, no need for `echo` and `cut`.

Comment: It seems it works indeed ! I don't have the error anymore. But a second command has exactly the same error on the first '$' : `&& number=$(grep '/' '\$input.element_identifier'".phy" | wc -l)`. It's a problem with Cheetah, I don't know why it's happening because it's works fine as a simple bahs command

Comment: Is the error on the `$` of the `$(...)`? Then it seems it's not able to execute a sub-shell. You could try to use `\`...\`` instead of `$(...)`.

Comment: The code you show is `bash` code but not `Cheetah` so how can we help? Please show us more code, at least few lines of `Cheetah` code.

Comment: sorry, it's edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to screen (escape with a backslash) every `$` sign that you want to pass to bash, else `Cheetah` tries to interpret them:

```
&& name=\$(echo '\$input.element_identifier'".phy" | cut -d _ -f 1)

&& number=\$(grep '/' '\$input.element_identifier'".phy" | wc -l)
```

etc.

Comment: It works, thank you :). I have other bugs to solve now, I will ask another question if needed.